# module.exports does not contain a default export

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules

I am trying to export my theme in my react app using `module.exports =

```
 module.exports = {
   defaultFontColor: "#282828",
   name: "Planswell",
   primary: primary,
   deemphasizedPrimary: "#e7f6ee",
   secondary: "#E4A432",
   danger: "#DF5F2B"...}`
```

in my file `whatever.js`, and i try to import it in another file using `import whatever from "themes/whatever.js";`

All was working well, but i updated Babel, and am now getting the error `Attempted import error: 'themes/whatever.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'whatever').`

What changed with Babel that caused this error? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Replace `module.exports = {...}` by  `export default {...}` in whatever.js.

Comment: Please provide description of what is inside `module.exports = { ... }` as your existing imports could not work anyway.

What version of Babel did you upgrade to and from? Can you post your babel config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only export in your `whatever.js` is

```
module.exports = {mod1, mod2, ...}
```

Then, assuming `whatever` is actually a module in your file, you should have never been able to import it using

```
import whatever from "themes/whatever.js";
```

The only way that would be possible is if in your `whatever.js` you did:

```
export default whatever;
```

Otherwise, you will have to destructure the import like so:

```
import {whatever, mod1, mod2, ...} from "themes/whatever.js";
```

Again, all this assumes that `whatever` is actually a module inside your `whatever.js` file e.g `const whatever = () => {...`. You don't make that part clear.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting should help you guide your way. When using `module.exports = {...}` syntax, the default export is the object.

You should try importing specific exported properties of the module such as `import { someModule } from 'themes/whatever.js'`. Optionally you can use

```js
import * as whatever from 'themes/whatever.js'

// Use it

whatever.myFunction()
```

Babel is pretty complex tool so I would check from which version you upgraded to and then looked at the change log to see what has changed. Babel has plethora of presets and plugins so it could be any combination, sorry no simple answer here.
To me it seems like perhaps you're using some different type of module.

Maybe you are using `@babel/preset-env` with combination of `browserslist` settings and you transpile to ES6 modules?

Comment: "*When using `module.exports = {...}` syntax, the default export is the object.*" - if that was true, the OP's code would work?

Comment: Because he's importing it as `import whatever from 'themes/whatever.js` instead of `import * as whatever from 'themes/whatever.js` in which case the "default" object is assigned to `whatever` variable.

`module.exports` is nothing magical. You just assign it a value. Often the value happens to be the object but it could be a string. It really depends how you consume such a module.

Comment: Yes, `import whatever from …` imports the default export as `whatever`, and you say `module.exports = x` sets the value of the default export to `x`, so what the OP has should work. Or do you mean that assigning `module.exports` sets the *namespace* object?

Comment: Because it really matters how you consume the module. And there are many ways different build tools handle this. I just hinted at using `import * as ...` as that could help because it intentionally avoids using `default` import. But it's really hard to give advice since we have no info on Babel settings etc.

Answer (score -2):

in your whatever.js you have exporting the as an object  that contain your component  so you have to export it like this

```
import {whatever} from "themes/whatever.js";
```

for your example to work you have to export your component without brackets

```
export {whatever}
```

Comment: Please explain why

Comment: because in your whatever.js you have exporting the as an object  that contain your component

Comment: But that object has no `.whatever` property, so I don't see how the `require("./whatever.js").whatever` could work. Also OP stated that they want to use ES6 module syntax with babel.

Comment: Setting module.exports allows the database_module function to be called like a function when required .if you want to use import it is recommanded to use export

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/